# Image is not adding to the imageview in Iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I'm doing an application using NSXmlParser. I'm getting data from server.I have to display details of the item including item image also.

I'm getting image data from parser, which is not adding to imageView .I'm using code as

```
UIImageView *warrantyCardImage;
warantyCardImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:warObj1.warrantyCardImagePath]]];
```

When I'm printing in console I'm getting value .By giving code as
printf("\n%s:",[warObj1.warrantyCardImagePath UTF8String]) and getting output as
    http://123.237.186.221:8080/Warrantify/Barcode/barcodefbbab1dd-9ff0-448b-8d46-dcebf5d11b37.png

If I'm giving code as

```
UIImageView *warrantyCardImage;
warantyCardImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://123.237.186.221:8080/Warrantify/Barcode/barcodefbbab1dd-9ff0-448b-8d46-dcebf5d11b37.png"]]];
```

it is working ,the image is adding to imageView

Guy's hope that I will get a quick response from your side.

Thanks to all,
Sri Lakshmi.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your data object is really being formed correctly. You are assuming it is in your sample.

```
UIImageView *warrantyCardImage;
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://123.237.186.221:8080/Warrantify/Barcode/barcodefbbab1dd-9ff0-448b-8d46-dcebf5d11b37.png"]];
if(imageData)
{
  warantyCardImage.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
else
{
  NSLog(@"sadness");
}
```

You are using a synchronous download method which maybe isnt the best. Explore the docs around NSURLDownload http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html which might serve you better.

Comment: Thank u very much. I came to know that data object is not formed correctly. Now it is working .

Comment: If you don't mark an answer as accepted then People here will stop answering your questions